# Trying to create new NSTextView every time the attributed string exceeds a certain height?

Tags: swift, macos, nsnotificationcenter, nstextview, nscollectionview

I'm trying to add a new NSTextView to the last index in my collection view every time the attributed string exceeds a certain bounds. The code works perfectly until the 5th item then it starts its starts creating an item every time the enter button is pressed. I'm thinking its a bug but im not sure. if any one can show me a better way to do it or improve the current code I have I would appreciate it. Below is my code:

Here is the CollectionViewItem

```
class DocumentItem: NSCollectionViewItem {

   var itemView: DocumentTextView?
   
   
   
   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       self.itemView?.wantsLayer = true
       
       
   
       // Do view setup here.
   }

   override func loadView() {
       self.itemView = DocumentTextView(frame: NSZeroRect)
       self.view = self.itemView!
       
   }

   func getView() -> DocumentTextView {
       return self.itemView!
   }
   
   
   
}
```

Here is the collectionView datasource

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return DocList.count
        }
            
        
func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
       
            let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue:  "DocumentItem"), for: indexPath)
            
            return item
}
```

Here is the NSTextView subclass

```
class DocumentTextView: NSTextView {
    
    
    var theContainer = NSTextContainer()
    var theStorage = NSTextStorage()
    var theManager = NSLayoutManager()
    
    
    var table = NSTextTable()
    var pdfPage: PDFPage?
    
    


   

    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: NSRect(origin: frameRect.origin, size: NSSize(width: 800, height: 1131 )), textContainer: theContainer)
        theStorage.addLayoutManager(theManager)
        theManager.addTextContainer(theContainer)
        self.textContainerInset = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
        self.textContainer?.widthTracksTextView = true
        self.textContainer?.heightTracksTextView = true
        self.textContainer?.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        self.maxSize = NSSize(width: 800, height: 1131)
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.fromHexString("ffffff")!
        self.isRichText = true
       

    
        
    }
  


   
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
        
    }
}
```

Here is the function bringing the bug

```
  func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        var textView = notification.object as? DocumentTextView
        let numberOfItems = theDocumentOutlineView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        let theLastTextView = theDocumentOutlineView.item(at: numberOfItems - 1) as! DocumentItem
        if textView == theLastTextView.itemView {
            print(textView?.attributedString().size())
            if (textView?.attributedString().size().height)! >= 1106.0 {
                self.DocList.append(2)
                var set = Set<IndexPath>()
                set.insert(NSIndexPath(forItem: self.DocList.count - 1 , inSection: 0) as IndexPath)
                theDocumentOutlineView.insertItems(at: set)
                theDocumentOutlineView.scrollToItems(at: set, scrollPosition: NSCollectionView.ScrollPosition.top)
                var newFirstResponder = theDocumentOutlineView.item(at: self.DocList.count - 1) as! DocumentItem
                newFirstResponder.itemView?.delegate = self
                self.view.window?.makeFirstResponder(newFirstResponder.itemView)
                
            
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are appending the textView at the last one of `theDocumentOutlineView`, then, it means that `if textView == theLastTextView.itemView` might be true each time for it (since you make it firstResponder too), AND if its text is big enought, it will pass the height test. So you'll add it again.

Comment: @Larme any ideas on how I can solve that?

Comment: Is `theDocumentOutlineView` a `NSCollectionView`?

Comment: @Willeke yeah I mistakenly called it an outline view

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke I thought this was a mre, the DocumentTextView is just a custom NSTextView and that is the item of the NSCollectionView. if you need more information I would provide it

Comment: It tried your code and I don't see any issues.

Comment: @Willeke hmmm, what possibly could be the problem ?

Comment: Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project?

Comment: @Willeke ive edited the information to put all necessary information about the problem. I would appreciate if you could look at it. Thank you very much bro

Comment: What is the frame size and the item size of the collection view? Is the 5th item the first item where `scrollToItems` is scrolling? Do you set the contents and delegate of the text view of existing items? Do you store the contents of an edited text view in `DocList`? What is printed by `print(textView?.attributedString().size())`?

Comment: @Willeke The item size of the collection view is exactly the size of the DocumentTextView, the frame size of the collectionView is x: 20, y: 0, width: 806, height: 723. The DocList is a list of integers and I initialised it with one integer which is 1

Comment: @Willeke you said you tried the code and it was working fine. I'll appreciate if I can see how you wrote the datasource for the collectionView and other aspects

Comment: @Willeke I noticed when the item size of the collection view is (200, 250). the error doesn't occur

Comment: @Willeke sorry it takes more items in the collectionView for it to occur

Comment: I replaced my code by your code so I don't have my code anymore. I am getting way too many new items now.

Comment: @Willeke any ideas on what the problem might be?

Comment: Maybe calling `makeFirstResponder` (ends editing) inside `textDidChange` doesn't work. Items are reused, the last item can be a reused previous item if only one item is visible.

Comment: @Willeke what do you think I could do? don't really know what else do to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my test project, maybe it helps. The delegate of the text view is its view controller, the `NSCollectionViewItem`. The view controller of the collection view also receives `NSText.didChangeNotification` notifications to check the length of the text. `heightTracksTextView` of the text container is `false`.

ViewController:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSCollectionViewDataSource, NSCollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: NSCollectionView!
    var docList: [DocumentObject] = [DocumentObject(index: 0, string: NSAttributedString(string: "New 0"))]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.register(DocumentItem.self, forItemWithIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("DocumentItem"))
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(textDidChange),
            name: NSText.didChangeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return docList.count
    }
            
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, itemForRepresentedObjectAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> NSCollectionViewItem {
        if let item = collectionView.makeItem(withIdentifier: NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier("DocumentItem"),
            for: indexPath) as? DocumentItem {
            item.representedObject = docList[indexPath.item]
            return item
        }
        return NSCollectionViewItem()
    }

    @objc func textDidChange(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let textView = notification.object as? NSTextView {
            if let theLastItem = self.collectionView.item(at: self.docList.count - 1) as? DocumentItem,
                textView === theLastItem.itemView {
                //if textView.attributedString().size().height >= 1106.0 {
                print("\(textView.attributedString().size().height) \(textView.layoutManager!.usedRect(for: textView.textContainer!).size.height)")
                if let textContainer = textView.textContainer,
                    let heigth = textView.layoutManager?.usedRect(for: textContainer).size.height,
                    heigth >= 1106.0 {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if let window = self.view.window,
                            window.makeFirstResponder(nil) { // end editing of previous item
                            self.docList.append(DocumentObject(index: self.docList.count - 1, string: NSAttributedString(string: "New \(self.docList.count)")))
                            let set: Set = [IndexPath(item: self.docList.count - 1, section: 0)]
                            self.collectionView.insertItems(at: set)
                            self.collectionView.scrollToItems(at: set, scrollPosition: NSCollectionView.ScrollPosition.top)
                            if let newItem = self.collectionView.item(at: self.docList.count - 1) as? DocumentItem {
                                window.makeFirstResponder(newItem.itemView)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

DocumentItem:

```
class DocumentItem: NSCollectionViewItem, NSTextViewDelegate {

    var itemView: DocumentTextView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    override func loadView() {
        self.itemView = DocumentTextView(frame: NSZeroRect)
        self.view = self.itemView!
        self.itemView?.delegate = self
    }
    
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
            if let item = representedObject as? DocumentObject {
                itemView?.textStorage?.setAttributedString(item.string)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func textDidEndEditing(_ notification: Notification) {
        if let item = representedObject as? DocumentObject {
            item.string = itemView?.textStorage?.copy() as! NSAttributedString
        }
    }

}
```

DocumentObject:

```
class DocumentObject {

    var index: Int
    var string: NSAttributedString
    
    init(index: Int, string: NSAttributedString) {
        self.index = index
        self.string = string
    }

}
```